# Cannot build docker after I changed anything in the code

Tags: reactjs, asp.net, docker, asp.net-web-api, docker-compose

I try to make a webapp with React frontend and .Net Core backend. I tried to containerize them.
frontend.docker:

```
FROM node:20.9.0-alpine
COPY frontend /frontend

# build frontend
WORKDIR /frontend
RUN npm ci
RUN npm run build

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

backend.docker

```
#For more information, please see https://aka.ms/containercompat

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:7.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443
EXPOSE 5555

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src

COPY ["./RedditAPI/RedditAPI.csproj", "/src"]
RUN dotnet restore "/src/RedditAPI.csproj"
COPY ./RedditAPI .
RUN dotnet build "/src/RedditAPI.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "/src/RedditAPI.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish/p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS http://+:5555
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "RedditAPI.dll"]
```

docker-compose

```
version: "3.9"
services:
 frontend:
   build:
    context: .
    dockerfile: frontend.dockerfile
  image: frontend:latest
  container_name: frontend
  ports:
    - "3000:3000"
  environment:
    - CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true
backend:
  container_name: backend
  build:
    context: .
    dockerfile: backend.dockerfile
  image: backend:latest
  environment:
    ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT: Development
    ASPNETCORE_URLS: http://+:5555
  ports:
    - "5555:5555"
```

When I build it first, it will build perfectly, but when I change something in the frontend code, add new html tag, anything, its giving me this:

```
=> [4/5] RUN npm ci                                                                                                               
14.0s 
=> => # (node:1) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak 
detected. 
11 close listeners added to [TLSSocket]. Use  
=> => # emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit                                                                                     
=> => # (node:1) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak 
detected. 
11 close listeners added to [TLSSocket]. Use  
=> => # emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
=> => # (node:1) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak 
detected. 
11 close listeners added to [TLSSocket]. Use  
=> => # emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I had the same error in the past few months. I think it's related to a slow internet connection. I solved the issue by connecting to my mobile hotspot. Could it be that you have a slow internet connection?

Comment: @stonith404 maybe, but why does it only happen if I change something in frontend?

Comment: The step that fails is `npm ci`. This step reruns every time you change something in the frontend.

Comment: And what can I do? I cant buy faster internet at the moment

Comment: It's probably a temporary bug of npm, because it has worked for me in the past even with slow internet. I can't guarantee that the internet is the issue, but for me it was. If you can't use e.g a mobile hotspot, you could use a pipeline that builds your Docker image (e.g GitHub Workflows)

Comment: @stonith404 can you show me a guide about build Docker Image in Github Workflows?